# Any way to swap Enter and Shift-Enter input commands in Edit-Mode, Jupyter Notebook?

Tags: ipython, jupyter-notebook

I just started using ipython/jupyter notebook. The Shift-Enter (run current cell) and Enter (insert newline) commands are frustrating to use. I would like to swap the commands for those two inputs in edit-mode.

So:

Shift-Enter: (insert newline)

Enter: (run current cell)

Is there some way to remap commands for jupyter notebook? A config file maybe? It sounds like ipython notebook did not always work this way ([Enter in the IPython console inserts new line instead of executing current line after kernel restart #2696](https://github.com/spyder-ide/spyder/issues/2696)). The solution to the linked github issue seems to be "just use shift-enter," and I was unable to find a solution on google.

I have the following versions:

```
ipykernel (4.5.2)
ipython (5.3.0)
jupyter (1.0.0)
notebook (4.4.1)
```

Comment: Not meaning to do necromancy, but since most instant messengers use it swapped, I'd be very interested in the answer.

Answer (score 2):

EDIT:

On newer JupyterLab (I'm now on 2.2.5), there's now a Keyboard Shortcuts settings file (under Settings > Advanced Settings Editor). Unfortunately, it seems that a swap between Shift+Enter and Enter is no longer possible, so that when adding Enter as a run-current-cell key, Shift+Enter still runs the current cell (i.e., if one adds Enter as a run-current-cell key, it can no longer add a new line in the current cell).

OLDER ANSWER:

An old question, but worth an answer for people using JupyterLab (Version 0.35.6, Windows 10):

1. Go to Settings > Advanced Settings Editor. A Settings tab will open.
2. On the sidebar of the Settings tab, click Keyboard Shortcuts. Two inner-tabs will open: System Defaults and User Overrides.
3. Copy the following into User Overrides to replace Shift+Enter with Enter (note that there's no need to explicitly define Shift+Enter as the keyboard shortcut for "new line").

The actual override here is the value "Enter", which replaces the default value "Shift Enter":

```
    {
       "runmenu:run": {
          "command": "runmenu:run",
          "keys": [
             "Enter"
          ],
          "selector": "[data-jp-code-runner]",
          "title": "Run",
          "category": "Run Menu"
      }, 
      "notebook:run-cell-and-select-next": {
          "command": "notebook:run-cell-and-select-next",
          "keys": [
            "Enter"
          ],
          "selector": ".jp-Notebook.jp-mod-editMode",
          "title": "Run Cell and Select Next",
          "category": "Notebook Operations"
       }
    }
```

4. Hit the save icon on the upper right corner.

End result:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Extending upon the answer by @OfirD, it seems that the following keyboard shortcuts user preference JSON does the trick in recent versions of JupyterLab:

```json
{
    "shortcuts": [
        {
            "args": {},
            "command": "notebook:run-cell-and-select-next",
            "keys": [
                "Shift Enter"
            ],
            "selector": ".jp-Notebook.jp-mod-editMode",
            "disabled": true
        },
        {
            "args": {},
            "command": "notebook:run-cell-and-select-next",
            "keys": [
                "Enter"
            ],
            "selector": ".jp-Notebook.jp-mod-editMode",
        },
        {
            "args": {},
            "command": "runmenu:run",
            "keys": [
                "Shift Enter"
            ],
            "selector": "[data-jp-code-runner]",
            "disabled": true
        },
        {
            "args": {},
            "command": "runmenu:run",
            "keys": [
                "Enter"
            ],
            "selector": "[data-jp-code-runner]",
        },
    ]
}
```

Comment: Doesn't seem to do the trick for me (Jupyter Notebook 6.5.3, Linux)

Answer (score 1):

Open up a notebook, and under [Help] you can find [Edit Keyboard Shortcuts]. For versions before 5.0, the documentation I linked below has a detailed explanation as to what command you can run to change the shortcuts.

Source: https://jupyter-notebook.readthedocs.io/en/stable/examples/Notebook/Custom%20Keyboard%20Shortcuts.html

Comment: I'm also having the same issue and this solution doesn't seem to work, since the shortcut is located in "Edit" mode which apparently cannot be changed.